# Multiple log files

Tags: python, logging

I'm just acquainting myself with the logging module and am confused about the proper way to handle different levels. This [flow chart](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) indicates that nothing below the set level gets passed to the logger object so why would anyone log anything below the set level? Should I make multiple log file? For example, `logging.basicConfig(filename='general_log.log',level=logging.WARNING)` and `logging.basicConfig(filename='detailed_log.log',level=logging.DEBUG)` in a single script?

Comment: Because you will have logging calls of all different levels in your script, but when you e.g. release it, you might change the level to only show fatal errors.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. So the answer is to change the logging level? So I could only be logging warnings and up but if it has a serious crash and I want to see everything I change it to show me debug and up?

Comment: @G Warner Yes, that's the idea. I'd agree with the answer by haifzhan.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple logging Levels are for different purposes.
For example as a developer when you are developing some new functionalities, you can set your logging level to `DEBUG` which can help you debug your code and you can set your logging level to `INFO` when run your program in production. All the debug level logging will be muted.

You can make multiple log files. For example if you want to trace the `ERROR` logs easier, you can log them into a separate file and it saves time to find them in your regular log file.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

```
This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.
```

Calling `logging.basicConfig` a second time likely won't do anything.

To log to multiple files, you'll need to configure more than one handler:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(name)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s() %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file1': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'general_log.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'file2': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'detailed_log.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['file1', 'file2'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    }
}
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```